# Not matching schema problems when appending list of CSV's into existing file geodatabase table?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, csv, append

So far I have the following code for creating the FGDB table and defining fields which works just fine. But when I try to append a list of csv's to this table I always get a matching schema error.

Do you have any idea, what may be wrong? Code and csv structure posted below.

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Desktop\\python_script"
gdb = "FileDatabase.gdb"

if arcpy.Exists(gdb):
    print "Database exists."
else:
    print "Database doesn't exist."
    fgdbPath = "C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Desktop\\python_script"
    fgdbName = "FileDatabase.gdb"
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(fgdbPath, fgdbName)
    print "Database has been created."

tabPath = "C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Desktop\\python_script\\FileDatabase.gdb"
tab = "Table"
fullPath = tabPath + "\\" + tab

if arcpy.Exists(fullPath):
    print "FGDB table exists."
else:
    print "FGDB table doesn't exist. Table will be created."
    arcpy.CreateTable_management(tabPath, tab)
    arcpy.AddField_management (fullPath, "transect", "LONG", "", "", "", "", "", "REQUIRED")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fullPath, "point", "LONG", "", "", "", "", "", "REQUIRED")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fullPath, "Xcoord", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "", "REQUIRED")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fullPath, "Ycoord", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "", "REQUIRED")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fullPath, "date", "DATE", "", "", "", "", "", "REQUIRED")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fullPath, "depth", "LONG", "", "", "", "", "", "REQUIRED")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fullPath, "paramA", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "", "REQUIRED")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fullPath, "paramB", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "", "REQUIRED")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fullPath, "paramC", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "", "REQUIRED")
    arcpy.AddField_management (fullPath, "notice", "TEXT", "", "", "", "", "", "REQUIRED")
    print "Table has been created."
```

For appending listed csv's I'm using the following script:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Desktop\\python_script"

csvList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.csv")
arcpy.Append_management(csvList, workspace + "\\" + "FileDatabase.gdb" + "\\" + "Table", "TEST")
```

The csv files are without header and look like this:

```
1,5,504577.885850,1158507.476675,15.04.2015,40,3.56,0.007,23.34,"text"
1,6,504577.885850,1158507.476675,15.04.2015,40,3.56,0.007,23.34,"text"
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please see our help section on how to ask questions most suitable for this forum: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  Could you please refine this into a single question?  As this stands, I see several questions: 1) How to merge multiple csv's, 2) How to convert csv to FGDB table, 3) How to create a FGDB?, 4) How to use logic to check if a table exists in FGDB?...

Comment: Check out the Append tool, and pay special attention to the `schema_type` parameter.  That should get you on your way to a point where you can restructure your question, as @Aaron recommends.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I restructured my question and I also included my code. Would appreciate any help with the schema_type parameter, since it keeps causing problems in my code.

Comment: What is the precise wording of the "matching schema error" that you see when running the code that you have posted?

Answer (score 1):

Change the flag `TEST` to `NO_TEST`. Name your fields in the table you create field1, field2,,, fieldx rather than proper field names as your source csv has none.  You can assign field aliases instead when you create the table.